# How to embed font to all page with nuxt js

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I just embed google font to the global setting in nuxt.config.js

```
 link: [
      { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' }
    ]
```

But how to apply this font to every page .

Answer (score 33):

### New answer

Use @nuxt/google-fonts package: https://nuxt.com/modules/google-fonts

It's trivial to use and supports a bunch of options including downloading the fonts.

---

### Old answer

**If you want to include the font within your app so you're serving it**

Download the font from: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto?selection.family=Roboto (Open the drawer and download the `.zip` file).

1. Unpack the contents of the .zip into `./assets/fonts/*` (create it if it does not exist).
2. Create `./assets/fonts/roboto.css` and place the following in it:

```
/* cyrillic-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu72xKOzY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0460-052F, U+1C80-1C88, U+20B4, U+2DE0-2DFF, U+A640-A69F, U+FE2E-FE2F;
}
/* cyrillic */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu5mxKOzY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0400-045F, U+0490-0491, U+04B0-04B1, U+2116;
}
/* greek-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7mxKOzY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+1F00-1FFF;
}
/* greek */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4WxKOzY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0370-03FF;
}
/* vietnamese */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7WxKOzY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+1EA0-1EF9, U+20AB;
}
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu7GxKOzY.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Roboto'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxK.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

(You can find this CSS by going to https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto).

Then change `nuxt.config.js` to include the CSS file in the `css` property:

```
module.exports = {
  /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: [
    '~/assets/fonts/roboto.css'
  ]
}
```

Then you apply `font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;` to your text elements.

---

**Using the font on every page**

Create a `./assets/css/styles.css` file with the following in it:

```
body
{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

Then as above include the CSS file in the `nuxt.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  css: [
    '~/assets/fonts/roboto.css',
    '~/assets/css/styles.css'
  ]
}
```

Same applies for any asset like other fonts, icons, framework css etc.

Comment: If you downloaded the actual font files, why are you still referencing them from `https://fonts.gstatic.com`?

Comment: Seems that the website is dead

Answer (score 24):

**QUICK**

In your nuxt.config.js fi

```
head: {
  ...
  ...
  link: [
    {
      rel: 'icon',
      type: 'image/x-icon',
      href: '/favicon.ico'
    },
    {
      rel: 'stylesheet',
      href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700'
    }
  ]
}
```

And in your layouts/default.vue or any other layout file that you are using add the style tag

```
<style scoped>
#app {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 5):

It is simple like this

1. Go to Google fonts and select your font style e.g [Montserrat](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat)
2. Got to `nuxt.config.js` and add your font url as shown here

> ```
> export default {  
>  head: {
>         meta: [],
>           link: [
>        { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap"'}
>      ]
>    }
> ```

3. Go to your nuxt project -> layouts directory -> `default.vue` file and add class named `app` ( or whatever name you want) in `v-app` tag as shown here

> ```
>  <v-app dark class="app"> 
>
>       --your app goes here -- 
>
>   </v-app>
> ```

4. In the same file style option add the following lines in the class body you defined above

   ```
    <style>
    .app{
      font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    }
    </style>
   ```

   Make sure class is defined in v-app tag and use  `<style>` and not  `<style scoped>` to take effect of whole project

Answer (score 1):

Update your CSS with the following rule:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
```

If you don't have CSS stylesheet setup yet, create a new file in `assets` directory named i.e. `main.css`. Inside it put the code above and save it. Then edit `nuxt.config.js` adding this piece of code after `head` object:

```js
css: [
  '@/assets/main.css'
],
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried many ways to add a custom font to a nuxt + vuetify project but no one worked correctly.

Finally I created a `global.scss` in `assets` folder file and addressed it in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
css: ['~assets/global.scss'],
```

and in `global.scss` file:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'my-custom-font';
    src: local('my-custom-font'), url('path/to/font') format('truetype');
}

.v-application {   
   font-family: 'my-custom-font' !important;
}

// or 

#app { 
    font-family: 'my-custom-font';
}
```

This worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you can do these steps:
1__define your font in as a custom varriable in a seprated file in your assests directory,for example variables.scss, like this:

```css
$body-font-family: Roboto;
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass';
```

2__then in the nuxt.config.js,you should add a stylesheet link in the head, like this:

```js
head: {
  link: [
    { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|Libre+Baskerville&display=swap' }
  ]
},
```

3__then it is neccessary to enable treeshaking in the vuetify and set your customvariables,like this:

```js
vuetify: {
  customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
  treeShake: true
},
```