# nuxt vuetify google font

Tags: vuetify.js, nuxt.js, google-font-api

I use Nuxt with vuetify. And I would like to use google fonts. Unfortunately it is not possible to overwrite the default font Roboto with a main.styl file. The goal in the main.stly is to overwrite the vuetify styl. How is that possible that I overwrite everything with my font (also buttons).  Thank you very much for your help

> nuxt.config.js

```
{
    rel: 'stylesheet',
    href:
      'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Serif'
  }
css: [
'~/assets/style/app.styl',
'~/assets/style/main.styl'css:],
```

> main.styl

```
body{
font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;}
```

[image 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSLUo.png)

[image 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnODm.png)

Comment: You can try, `body{font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif !important;}`

Comment: thanks for your help. Unfortunately it didn't work out

Comment: maybe, `<style> html {  font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif; } </style>` in your layouts/default.vue

Comment: Thanks for your Help. That's what I thought. Unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: Check the answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51436344/how-to-embed-font-to-all-page-with-nuxt-js/60782370#60782370

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it is still relevant, but you can try the following:

In your `nuxt.config.js`:

```
vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.styl']
}
```

And in `*/assets/variables.styl`:

```
$body-font-family = 'Noto Serif', serif
```

Comment: in nuxt.config.js, the attribute vuetify.treeShake must be explicitly set to true, else this won't work

Answer (score 1):

[image: snap of nuxt.config.js]

In nuxt.config.js you can add as follows and it automatically takes from google fonts.

You do not have to specify the font in your scss files. It automatically does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

This way it works for me: 
in app.styl, which you specify as entry-point for your styles:

```
$body-font-family = 'Ubuntu'
@require '~vuetify/src/stylus/main'
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Too bad with me it doesn't work. look the image 02

Answer (score 0):

In your `nuxt.config.js`:

```
vuetify: {
    customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
    treeShake: true, // IMPORTANT! Else the default variables won't be overwritten
}
```

In your `assets/variables.scss`:

```
$body-font-family: 'FontName', sans-serif !default;
```

Linking any documentation is useless because this part of the nuxt documentation is totally ambiguous and misses a lot of things.