# How can I turn off Google fonts and Material design icons in Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I am developing an internal company app that does not reach out to the internet, therefore I can not use CDNs or Google Fonts.

In my developer console for Chrome (and not Firefox for some reason) I get errors pointing to the fact it get the following urls

https://dcn.jsdeliver.net/npm/@mdi/font@latest/materialdesignicons.min.css

and

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roberto:100,300,400,500,700,900&display=swap

How (in nuxt/vuetify) can I turn these off?

Comment: You could download and use those fonts locally as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68166329/8816585). If you **really** don't have any Internet connection, dump those files directly into the project from some storage (floppy disk).

Comment: Ah thanks, that might just work

Comment: Tell me if you have any issues with it. If it works, I'll post an answer below!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to set nuxtjs/vuetify to offline mode with this configuration:

```
{
  buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify'
  ],
  vuetify: {
    defaultAssets: false // <= this will disable autoloading Google font and MDI icons
  }
}
```

Then you can import these icons and fonts [as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51436344/how-to-embed-font-to-all-page-with-nuxt-js).